# Can I build GUI application, using kivy, which is dependent on other libraries?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, kivy

I want to make an GUI application using Kivy framework in Python. I am using Kivy for interface i.e. GUI design and Selenium, BeautifulSoup, CSV libraries for background purpose. Can anybody confirm that does Kivy work with other libraries too?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, Kivy is just a library providing window drawing and manipulation. What else your Python code does is not limited.